# Why is Num not shown with an Eq and Show constriant

Tags: haskell

In the Haskell report (p. 76 https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf) the type class hierarchy is shown as:

[image: Type class hierarchy]

But when I look at the definition of Num I get:

[image: :i Num in GHCI]

Why is Num not defined as `class Eq a, Show a => Num a where`?

Comment: IIRC, GHC did not fully comply with this, and wanted to allow defining a `Num` if there is no `Eq`, for example to allow data types where one can construct expressions with variables, like for a CAS.

Comment: See https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-4-1.html